# No type named 'Error' in module 'Foundation'

Tags: ios, swift, namespaces, foundation

I have created a class named `Error`. Now, there's also the class `Error` in Foundation and I still need to be able to access that one.
What I usually do in this case is apply proper namespacing:

```
Foundation.Error
```

However, I am getting the following error message:

> No type named 'Error' in module 'Foundation'

I've checked the documentation to verify that `Error` is actually from `Foundation`:

[image: error class in foundation from the docs]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Swift.Error` should work.

Comment: You're right! Why is it not `Foundation` though, even though it's declared there?

Comment: What makes you think that? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/error says: Framework: Swift Standard Library

Comment: See the updated post.

Comment: I can't tell you *why* it is listed under Foundation, you don't even to import Foundation to use `Error`.

Comment: Hm, anyway, thanks! If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. Or should I delete this question? Maybe too trivial...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Error` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/error)
is defined in the Swift Standard Library. You don't even need to import
Foundation in order to use it:

```
$ swift
Welcome to Apple Swift version 4.2 (swiftlang-1000.11.37.1 clang-1000.11.45.1). Type :help for assistance.
  1> var e: Error?
e: Error? = nil
  2>
```

The fully qualified name is therefore `Swift.Error`.

The (useful) [`localizedDescription`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/error/2292912-localizeddescription) property however is defined in the Foundation
framework, as a protocol extension method.